# Quit for loop functions after 5 iterations

Tags: java

The original homework question was:

Write a Java program that asks the user if he/she likes Java programming.

• If the user answers yes, then it displays a congratulating message (use your imagination),
and terminates.

• Now, if the user answers no, then the fun starts.

– The program should ask Are you sure you don’t like Java programming?.

∗ If the user answers no, then it should display Hope you’ll get to like it soon...

∗ Otherwise, if the user answers yes, it should ask Are you really sure you don’t like Java programming?, and repeat.

· If the user keeps saying yes, then the program keeps asking Are you really really sure you don’t like Java programming?,

then Are you really really really sure you don’t like Java programming?.

And so on, every time printing one more really.

· This should stop when it reaches the point when it prints really 5 times. At that point, if the user still answers yes, it should print Too bad.., and terminate.

I have figured out the entirety of the question yet I can't figure out the last part:

This should stop when it reaches the point when it prints really 5 times. At that point, if the user still answers yes, it should print Too bad.., and terminate.

package lab7;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class problem7 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("Do you like java programming? 'yes' / 'no'");
    String input = scan.next();

    switch (input)  {
    case "yes" :
    case "Yes":
        System.out.println("Congratulations, you are an advanced intellectual");
        break;          
    case "no":
        System.out.println("Are you sure you don't like java programming?");

        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {

            String input2 = scan.next();

            switch (input2) {
            case "yes":
            case "Yes":
                String out = "";
                for (int inner = 0; inner  < i; inner++) {
                    out = out + "really, ";
                }
                System.out.println("Are you" + " " + out + " " + 
                        "sure you don't like java programming?");  

            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

The expected result after entering yes to the "Are you really, really, really, really, really,  sure you don't like java programming?"
should be "Too bad..." and this should follow the termination of the loop. My output is a simple termination of the loop however I don't know how to incorporate the "too bad"

Comment: You could just add `System.out.println("Too bad")` after the for loop.  Inside the for loop, add a case "no": that prints a message and then returns.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your for-loop, create a flag:

```
bool shouldExitLoop = false;
```

Then in your "yes" case:

```
shouldExitLoop = true;
```

Then below the end of the loop:

```
if (shouldExitLoop) break;
```

Ask a followup if this doesn't make sense. There are easier ways to structure this, code, but this is a relatively common design pattern, early termination from a complicated loop.